# What do these Java errors mean?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I know that my code still has flaws (its a work in progress). But I got these couple errors and I don't understand why.
Any help at all is appreciated thank you!!

theses are the errors

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\MailOrderEMH.java:27: error: variable numBoxes is already defined in method main(String[])
    int numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesString);
        ^
C:\Users\me\Documents\MailOrderEMH.java:70: error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
     while (enterAnother == "Y" || "y")
                                ^
  first type:  boolean
  second type: String
C:\Users\me\Documents\MailOrderEMH.java:102: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
            ( "Enter Number of Boxes: " );
            ^
3 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

and here is the code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // Imports JOptionPane class.

public class MailOrderEMH
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
    // Declare string variables
    String title;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String streetAddress;
String city;
String state;
String zip;
String numBoxesString;
int numBoxes;
int count = 1;
String enterAnother = "Y"; //INITILIZE the loop control variable

//get input values from user
numBoxesString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "Enter Number of Boxes: " );

//Conver srring to integer
int numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesString);

//get input values from user
 title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "What is your title ex. (Ms. Mr. Dr.) " );

//get input values from user
firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "Enter First Name: " );

//get input values from user
lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "Enter Last Name: " );

//get input values from user
streetAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "Enter Street Address: " );

//get input values from user
city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "Enter City: " );

//get input values from user
state = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "Enter State: " );

//get input values from user
zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( "Enter Zip Code: " );


while (count <= numBoxes)
{
    System.out.println( title + firstName + lastName );
    System.out.println( streetAddress );
    System.out.println( city + state + zip );
    System.out.println( "Box" + count + "of" + numBoxes);
    count = count + 1;
}
//get input values from user
enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
( " Do you want to produce more labels? Y or N " );

 while (enterAnother == "Y" || "y")
{
        //get input values from user
         title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "What is your title ex. (Ms. Mr. Dr.) " );

        //get input values from user
        firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "Enter First Name: " );

        //get input values from user
        lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "Enter Last Name: " );

        //get input values from user
        streetAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "Enter Street Address: " );

        //get input values from user
        city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "Enter City: " );

        //get input values from user
        state = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "Enter State: " );

        //get input values from user
        zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "Enter Zip Code: " );

        //get input values from user
        numBoxes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ( "Enter Number of Boxes: " );
}
// End program.
         System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: thank you for your help, but which error is this in reffereance to.  The second one?

Comment: I tried changing it to while (enterAnother.equal("Y" || "y")) and it still gives me the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Users\me\Documents\MailOrderEMH.java:27: error: variable numBoxes
>   is already defined in method main(String[])
>       int numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesString);

You've declared `numBoxes` twice

```
int numBoxes;
//...
int numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesString);
```

> C:\Users\me\Documents\MailOrderEMH.java:70: error: bad operand types
>   for binary operator '||'
>        while (enterAnother == "Y" || "y")

The condition needs to resolve to `true` or `false`, where `"y"` is a `String`, which makes no sense.  Also `==` is not how you compare `String`s in Java, a simpler solution would be to do something like...

```
 while ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(enterAnother) {
```

> C:\Users\me\Documents\MailOrderEMH.java:102: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
>               ( "Enter Number of Boxes: " );

`JOptionPane#showInputDialog` returns a `String` value, so trying to assign a `String` to an `int` won't work.

You could do something like...

```
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number of Boxes: ");
if (value != null) {
    numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(value);
}
```

Remember, `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` can also return `null` if the dialog is canceled by the user, so you need to prepare for that eventuallaity

Comment: Suggesting `enterAnother == "y" || enterAnother == "Y"` is much better than `"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(enterAnother)`, seeing that OP is a beginner and misunderstanding how `||` in C-like languages differs from "or" in English.

Comment: @Rhymoid Except `==` is not how `String` comparison works in Java

Comment: Right! My mistake. Still, I'd make the steps a bit more explicit, with `"y".equals(enterAnother) || "Y".equals(enterAnother)` as an (intermediate) suggestion.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you very much I did what you said and it fixed all of them except for the numBoxes I still get  error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
   ( "Enter Number of Boxes: " );                                                       and I did what you said and I put String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number of Boxes: ");
 if (value != null) {
     numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(value);
} but I still get the error

Comment: I figured out that it taking about the second one in my code tward the bottom like 98.  because its a while loop how can I get another input for numboxes if the answer "Y" with out I yelling at me for decaring sring value twice and why is the error ony on the second one

Comment: You just need to ask the user if they want to repeat.  May be using a `int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Would you like to add another?"
    "More", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"Yes", "No"}, options[0]);`.  If it returns `0` then the answer is "yes"